# Animator/AnimatorSet issue on some devices

Tags: android, animation, huawei-mobile-services, animator, animatorset

I have made some tests with the ObjectAnimator class on some devices and everything is OK except for one device : Huawei P8 Lite 2017.

On this device, the View "disappears" when the animation starts and "appears" at the end. 
The issue appears only when I'm using AnimatorSet/Animator (Java code or XML), but animations which use the old Animation class (TranslateAnimation, AlphaAnimation...) are working well.

Here is the list of devices where there is no issue :
Nexus 5
Nexus 5X
Nexus 9
HTC One M9
Samsung GS4
Pixel XL
Alcatel OneTouch Idol 5

What is the problem with this Huawei ?

**Edit** : 
I have made some other tests, the issue seems to be only with Rotation animation.

```
ObjectAnimator r = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, View.ROTATION_Y, 540);
r.setDuration(5000);
r.start();
```

works on every devices except the Huawei.

If I replace ROTATION_Y by ALPHA or TRANSLATION_X or Y, it is working on the Huawei.

Here is a link with more or less the same issue :
[ObjectAnimator causes ImageView to disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474467/objectanimator-causes-imageview-to-disappear)

Comment: i have no idea what `disappears` / `appears` really mean but most likely animators are disabled under `developer options`

Comment: As if View.VISIBILITY = INVISIBLE. I have checked in dev options, Animation scale is on "1X"

Comment: Animator is enabled (1X).

Comment: so no animations work on that phone? even those in home launcher app?

Comment: Only in my app. I have tested a ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(Rotation).setDuration(1 second), the View appears, becomes invisible for 1 second, and appears at the end of the animation. This is crazy.

Comment: so your `ObjectAnimator` is wrong and nobody will tell you why without your code

Comment: tried: `myView.animate().setDuration(1000).rotationBy(360);`?

Comment: Same result... :(

Comment: so i have no idea... ;-(

Comment: Have the same problem with animate().rotationY on some Huawei devices... any luck to solve it ?

Comment: Hi. May be my problem somehow related to yours? I have a trobles with disappearing of animated textview. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55744220/textview-disappears-after-animation-on-some-devices

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with Huawei devices (P9 Lite).

The problem is "camera distance" during transformation. Default value for camera distance for Huawei is too small and you should set it by code:

```
image.setCameraDistance(float)
```

From documentation:

> If you want to specify a distance that leads to visually consistent
>   results across various densities, use the following formula:

```
float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
 view.setCameraDistance(distance * scale);
```

Comment: Thanks but set it to what? What the distance variable equals to?