# TextView disappears after animation on some devices

Tags: java, android, animation, rotation

I have this animation code which rotate TextView by 360 after some action. On most part of devices it works well but on some of them the view disappears after the animation

I can't reproduce the bug locally on phone or emulator but have some video recordings from users who reported bug on Google play.

Some devices with this problem: Huawei 荣耀畅玩 6X
honor6x, HUAWEIMate9lite, Huawei Honor 8

Link to video https://youtu.be/HwjlDjtuE1A

```
@BindingAdapter("animateView")
public static void setAnimateView(TextView textView, boolean animateView) {
    String prevText = textView2value.get(textView);
    String text = textView.getText().toString();
    if (animateView && (prevText != null && !prevText.isEmpty()) && text.isEmpty()) {
        textView.setRotationX(0);
        textView.animate()
                .rotationX(360)
                .setDuration(500)
                .start();
    }
    if (!textView.getText().toString().equals(prevText)) {
        textView2value.put(textView, text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very strange. In your video you have a drag&drop with no rotation animation, but in your code have rotation animation. This is a very general description of the problem. The bug may be in any other place.

Comment: Problem is wired. Rotation animation works correctly at all devices on which I've tried that personally. Such behaviour is not very common. From 1500 users I have near 10 reports of this problem.

Here is the whole code but I can't guess which other places put into the question https://github.com/usharik/CzechDeclensionQuiz

Comment: Also I expect some connections with this question but not sure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46845261/animator-animatorset-issue-on-some-devices